# How to send a message to a Channel on all Servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to send a message to all channels that are in all servers that are called "labycheck-shop" at 12 midnight.
I have already tried this but it did not work:

````js
cron.schedule('0 0 * * *', () => {
  const channel = client.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'labycheck-shop');
  channel.send('test')
})```

// (cron is node-cron)
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This feature can turn out to be spammy on the Discord API, so you might want to keep that in mind
2. I believe that you might be wanting to use `<Collection>.filter` instead of `<Collection>.find`.
   The find function in the Discord.js Collections works pretty much like `<Array>.find`, which returns the **first** result it gets true for.
   So what you'll want to do is, use `<Collection>.filter` to filter the guilds of that name, and then Loop through the array and send the message.

So kinda like this

```js
cron.schedule('0 0 * * *', () => {
    client.channels.cache.filter((ch) => ch.name === "labycheck-shop").forEach((channel) => channel.send("Ding dong it's 12 AM"));
});
```

That's how it should work out, I also checked the cron expression, and that looks fine as well